# How to determine different bit values given an integer value?

Tags: sql-server, integer, byte, bit

I have a SQL field (Integer type), and in this example, it holds the value "1024".

In looking at my documentation for the DB schema, this field can be parsed such that:

"Bit 0 means Default"
"Bit 1 means Opposite of bit 0"
"Bit 2 means Verified"
"Bit 3 means Duplicate"
"Bit 4 means Manual"
...

And it goes on all the way up to Bit 21.

I don't know what the Bit thing means or how it relates to the Integer value. I'm not even really sure how to google this (if that makes sense), so I'm hoping SO can help (or help me with the wording to use for Googling).

Thanks.

(added SQL-Server as a tag, but not sure if it's relevant here or not)

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 1 bit set?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bit field.  Have a read of these...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_field

The number is represented in binary as 0's and 1's (or bits), e.g. 00000100.  For each position there is a different meaning, e.g. for the first Bit it is a 0 so it means Default for example.

1024 as binary is 10000000000.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VR46 and @Quantumplate, I understand how this works now. The value in the field is an integer, and when converted to Binary (using language of choice), turns into something like: 010001000010 - Counting from the right, each digit represents a "Bit" and corresponds to a "lookup value" in the documentation. So it's possible for multiple Bits to be set to 1.

Thank you all.